# Use "where" and "limit" to child in @foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach, view, relationship

I want to display all user's profile into views and they posts. It's pretty simple:

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
{{ $profile->name }}
 @foreach($profile->posts as $post)
   {{$post->title}}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I want to display only the latests posts (->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4) ) and only accepted posts (->where('accept', 1)). How can I do that?

Comment: what is the database and version

Answer (score 0):

You already have what you need. You just need to put it all together.

```
@foreach($profile->posts()->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get() as $post)
```

I would consider creating a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) on your profile model. That way you can do something like $profile->latestPosts.

Or you can use the relationship to return exactly what you need.

```
public function latestPosts() {
    return $this->posts()->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();
}
```

Then you could use it as:

```
@foreach($profile->latestPosts() as $post)
    {{$post->title}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're using the `Query scope` the wrong way. Scopes are not meant to return a `Collection`, but a `Query` object. Also, your scope is more like a relation since it returns another entity.

Comment: You are right. I realized that it should just use the existing relationship. I've adjusted my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You need some codes like it on controller:

```
$profiles = Profile::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('accept', 1)
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

And add this one to blade file:

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
    {{ $profile->name }}
    @foreach($profile->posts as $post)
        {{$post->title}}
        @if ($loop->iteration == 4)
            @break
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tryed do that but it display me 4 posts but all users. I want to display 4 posts for any single user.

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. So you could remove limit from query and use [blade loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to lazy load the posts you need when loading the profiles in the controller.

```
$profile = Profile::with(['posts' => function ($post) {
    $post->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4);
}])->limit(10)->get();
```

then in the blade you can do the same as before

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
{{ $profile->name }}
 @foreach($profile->posts as $post)
   {{$post->title}}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

if you want to use a scope for `latestAccepted`, you can on the `Post` model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function scopeLatestAccepted($query)
    {
        return $query->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)
    }
}
```

Then lazy load it

```
$profile = Profile::with(['posts' => function ($post) {
    $post->latestAccepted();
}])->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: It displays me 4 posts but from all users. I want to display 4 posts from any single user.

Comment: @polishboy14f4 use `find($userId)` instead of `get()` edited my answer

Comment: I see but I want to display for example 10 users

Comment: then before the `get()` do a `limit(10)->get()`. Your question had nothing to do with the `Profiles` selected

Comment: I don't understand. You use find() instead get()

Comment: @polishboy14f4 re-edited my answer, guess it's faster that way ;)

Comment: So we are returning to starting point and problem is this same. You're code has a mistake. It would be `::with(['posts' => function ($query) {`

Comment: And now display 4 posts for all profiles and 4 to any profiles again.

Answer (score 0):

- what you have to do is pretty simple.

  1. create table users
  2. create table post
  3. create a relationships between the 2 tables
  4. write you code in controller to join the table and query all the users post based on his/her username or password

see sample screenshot for table relationships[image]

//Controller

```
Public function ViewPost(){

       $data['data']=DB::table('useratable')
        ->where('useratable.username','=', $uname)
        ->where('useratable.password','<=',$pwd)
        ->leftjoin('posttable', 'useratable.idusertable', '=', 'posttable.userid')
        ->orderby('posttable.idposttable','desc')
        ->get();
    }
```

//Route

```
Route::get('/view-post','YourController@ViewPost')
```

//view

```
@foreach($data as $r) 

     {{ $r->fullname}} <br>
     {{ $r->email}} <br>
     {{ $r->topic }} <br>
     {{ $r->content }} <br>
     {{ $r->datetime}} <br>
        ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Here I don't see solutuin of my problem